# How do I pass a MouseEvent parameter in a QML signal

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to propagate the MouseArea signals to a parent object, but using MouseEvent as the parameter type causes an import error.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import org.kde.plasma.core 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: linkRect

    signal clicked(MouseEvent mouse)

    ToolTipArea {
        id: tooltip
        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: linkRect.clicked(mouse)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the `var` type like this:

```
signal clicked(var mouse)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `QtObject` instead of `MouseEvent`.
Also this works for `KeyEvent` parameter in `KeyPressed` event.

```
signal clicked(QtObject mouse)
```

**Note:** The `QtObject` is base of these classes.